# TypeError: r.props.data is not a function - Material Table -Production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am using a material table in my react application, this is the npm package I am using, https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-table

In my development, I face no issues but when In production I am facing an error from the material table package. And this error is shown only once and when I refresh it, this error doesn't show again.

Please tell me a solution for this .

```
react-dom.production.min.js:209 TypeError: r.props.data is not a function
    at n.<anonymous> (material-table.js:288)
    at fa (react-dom.production.min.js:131)
    at as (react-dom.production.min.js:212)
    at pl (react-dom.production.min.js:255)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at qo (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at fl (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Zs (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
```

This is the component used

```
const renderRegistrations=()=>{
      return (
          <MaterialTable
            title="Registered Users"
            style={{marginLeft:25,marginRight:25,marginBottom:25,marginTop:25}}
            columns={columns}
            data={users}
            
            editable={{
              onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                    dispatch(AdminUpdateUserData(newData))
                    dispatch(fetchRegisteredUsers());
                    setTransition(() => TransitionUp);
                    setOpen({
                      state:true,
                      message:"Edited user successfully"
                    });
                  }, 600);
                }),
            }}
            options={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#121858',
                color: '#FFF'
              },
              searchFieldStyle:{
                marginRight:(width==='xs'||width==='sm')?20:((width==='md')?350:500)
              }
            }}
        />
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please add the actual code where you've added the component.

Comment: I have updated the component do check , Thank you

Comment: Does that happen on load?

Comment: yes, for now I have managed to check if the values is not loaded to an empty array that solved the issue for now ```data={users|[]}```